# XSLT to remove tags/attributes belonging to a namespace

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to use XSLT to remove tags/attributes belonging to a namespace. The difficulty is that tags from differnt namespaces can be embedded in each other.

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
  <Identifier Name="CollectionX"
          ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}"
          ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"  />

  <Properties>
    <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
    <Displayed>Reserved</Displayed>
    <Picture>Reserved.jpeg</Picture>
  </Properties>

  <WeakLinks>
    <Link Type="resource" Language="en-us"/>
  </WeakLinks>

</Collection>
```

I want to filter all tags/properties that do not belong to ns1 as long as they do not have any ns1 children.

So the result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
  <Identifier 
      ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}"
      ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"  />

  <Properties>
    <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
  </Properties>

</Collection>
```

How can I accoplish this with XSLT? Any help?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only, so far, correct answer containing a complete, short and easy solution that uses the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- overriding of the *identity rule*. Extensive explanation is also provided.

Comment: I would have given this question two upvotes if possible :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[not(attribute::ns1:*)
  and
    not(descendant-or-self::ns1:*)
   ]
 |
  @*[not(namespace-uri()='http://s1')]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
    <Identifier Name="CollectionX"
      ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}"
      ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"  />
    <Properties>
        <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
        <Displayed>Reserved</Displayed>
        <Picture>Reserved.jpeg</Picture>
    </Properties>
    <WeakLinks>
        <Link Type="resource" Language="en-us"/>
    </WeakLinks>
</Collection>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
   <Identifier ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}"
   ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"/>
   <Properties>
      <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
   </Properties>
</Collection>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule (template) copies every node "as-is**".
2. **There is just one template overriding the identity rule. This templates has no body -- meaning that it effectively filters (deletes) any matched node from being copied to the output**. The nodes matched are exactly the ones that must be filtered out: 1) any element that doesn't have attributes belonging to the namespace to which the prefix `ns1:` is bound and also isn't itself belonging to that namespace and also it has no descendent element nodes belonging to that namespace. And 2) any attribute that doesn't belong to that namespace.

**Remember**: Overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental and most powerful XSLT design pattern. More about this design pattern can be found **[here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: It would be nice if we could do `@ns1:*` also. Thanks +1.

Comment: @empo: Thanks, What do you mean? couldn't understand... It isn't possible to say: `self::attribute::ns1:*` -- two axes cannot be used in the same location step. Also this is wrong: `@*[not(starts-with(name(),'ns1:))]` -- because an attribute can belong to this namespace but its name  can have another prefix.

Comment: @empo: This cannot be used, because we want *not* to match such nodes ... :) And it is impossible to say: `@*[not(self::attribute::ns1:*)]`

Comment: Sorry, meaning: write `@ns0:*` in place of `@*[not(namespace-uri()='http://s1')]` after having declared (and excluded) the prefix for default namespace `http://s0`, but it seems not giving the expected result.

Comment: @empo: This is possible, but less efficient: `@*[count(.|../@ns1:*) > count(../@ns1:*))]`

Comment: @Dimitre.Novatchev I thought it was implied in the question based on my former understanding of namespace scope. Thanks for clarifying below and I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements with the `ns1` namespace by using `ns1:*`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@ns1:* | 
                                   node()[attribute::ns1:* | 
                                          descendant-or-self::ns1:*] | 
                                   text() | comment() | processing-instruction()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update**

I updated the XPath for matching attributes to `@ns1:*` to only capture attributes with the desired namespace. I also fixed the support for comments and processing instructions work in my testing. Given the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
  <Identifier Name="CollectionX"
          ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}"
          ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"  />
<!-- comment -->
  <Properties>
    <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
    <Displayed>Reserved</Displayed>
    <Picture>Reserved</Picture>
  </Properties>

  <WeakLinks>
    <Link Type="resource" Language="en-us"/>
  </WeakLinks>

</Collection>
```

The XSL above produces this output (tested with Saxon and MSXML).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Collection xmlns="http://s0" xmlns:ns1="http://s1">
  <Identifier ns1:GlobalID="{E436833B-B0A6-4E0D-804B-60052B767AE3}" 
              ns1:LocalID="{0130C866-7A91-4544-A82B-E0C0F2E3BCB2}"/>
  <!-- comment -->
  <Properties>
    <ns1:Collectible>1982</ns1:Collectible>
  </Properties>
</Collection>
```

**Update 2**

I removed my previous reference to attributes with no-namespace. [According to the XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes) which is [summarized very well here by @Dimitre.Novatchev](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/xmlandnetfx/thread/e2dac102-5ac3-4a94-ac83-e62a938d826d), an attribute with no namespace prefix belongs to "no-namespace", not the default namespace or the namespace of the parent node. If you do want to match these add `@*[parent::ns1:* and namespace-uri()=''] |` to the match expression in `<apply-templates  ...>`. This would apply a situation like  `<ns1:Collectible WhatIsMyNamespace="no-namespace">` where you want to match `WhatIsMyNamespace="no-namespace"`.

Comment: This solution doesn't produce the wanted answer. It violates the requirements that attributes not belonging to the given namespace must not be copied. Also, it will delete from the document any comments and/or any processing instructions.  -1

Comment: @empo thanks for your initial comments. I've removed the unnecessary xmlns:msxsl namespace.

Comment: @cordsen: RE: "According to the W3C summarized in this post, an attribute with no explicit namespace takes the namespace of it's parent node. If this is not what you want simply remove @*[parent::ns1:* and namespace-uri()=''] |." This is *not* true. Your understanding of the spec is incorrect. Regardless of the namespace of their parent element any attributes with unprefixed name belong to "no namespace". It is a general rule in XPath that any unprefixed name belongs to "no namespace".

Comment: @Dimitre.Novatchev that makes sense and I've updated again (and referred to your post elsewhere). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @cordsen: Thanks for the "ever-correct" being applied against my personna, but it is better to say that this is according the XPath Spec and even to provide a link to the relevant section.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev. I had a link to the MSDN forum which I have now I made more explicit.

Comment: @cordsen: Your current code still deletes PIs from the source XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre.Novatchev I see what you mean. I had tested with processing instructions at the top of the document but not as _in_ the document. Fixed. Thanks - I've learned much about namespaces through this question.

Comment: @cordsen: Good. I have reversed my downvote -- no more reasons for it :)